# Validation error from htmlvalidator.com using wp_enqueue_script that text/javascript is obsolete

Tags: wordpress, javascript, validation

This code was being flagged on my Wordpress website:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/simple-download-monitor/js/sdm_g_recaptcha.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en_GB&onload=sdm_reCaptcha&render=explicit&ver=4.9.5'></script>
```

The error:

> Media type `“text/javascript”` is obsolete, recommend `“application/javascript”` instead.

I contacted the plugin author and they stated that the final HTML code was generated by [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). So, is there any way to rectify this issue?

Comment: _What_ was reporting that "error"? The browser? Incidentally, that is really just a recommendation / notice - browsers will still understand it. However, what's more important, is the `Content-Type` HTTP response header that is being sent from your server.

Comment: https://www.htmlvalidator.com/ raised the error.

Comment: I dont' think this needs to be fixed.  Yes the new standard is `application/javascript`, but  `text/javascript` is very common and IE 8 or earlier won't work if you change to `application/javascript`. See on StackOverflow: [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)